# angular2 nb-bootstrap datepicker - use of 'this.' in a component

Tags: angular, datepicker, ng-bootstrap

Here is the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/p0UiEFlBs2WcjO2cwmgE

As you can see, in version 1, the calendar is broken, and it works in version 2.

In version 1, the function `isDisabled()` calls `this.isWeekend()`.
In version 2, I copied the same code in both functions.
Why is version 1 broken ???

Comment: where is version1\2?

Comment: I saw your code it is working perfectly fine. Except BigCell is included in the template

Comment: Sorry, my plunker was not very clear. Here is the code that works: http://plnkr.co/edit/laMMIgFVG3G2vMYM17TB?p=preview and here is the one that does not work: http://plnkr.co/edit/qj49JCR0Ysb2y1qk2NkT?p=preview